# Convert TIF to PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, tiff

I want to convert a TIF file into a PDF. When I search online, all I see is TIFF to PDF converters. I've tried following instructions from sites assuming that if a converter supports TIFF, it will support TIF conversion too, but in fact, it does not. How can I convert a TIF into PDF?

Comment: What's the difference between what your are finding and what you want...?  I don't see any.

Comment: tiff and tif are the same file type. Think about jpeg and jpg. If you manually remove the extra `f` from .tiff then do the converters work?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I am sorry I did not know I can simply add one more 'f' into the extension and it will do the job. thank you

Comment: No sweat man, sorry if you felt a harsh tone from me. I like to give concise comments/answers so that I avoid confusing people. Glad you have it figured out though! If I put my comment as an answer will you vote/accept it?

Comment: ohh sure. pls go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.TIFF and .TIF are the same file types. I would recommend manually removing/adding an `f` and see if you can convert it.

Answer (score 1):

both the extensions are same. tif or tiff doesn't matter. you can use one of the converters for tiff files.

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't answer the question. The question exists only because the author didn't knew tif and tiff were the same. The accepted answer said the same thing 1h later...

Comment: It doesn't help him make it work. Apparently the converter(s) he tried required the exact extension of "TIFF".  Most don't, though.